# Why static_cast make the destructor called

Tags: c++, static-cast

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define debug(x) cout << #x << ": " << (x) << endl;

class Base {
public:
  void f() { cout << "Base:f()" << endl; }
  ~Base() { cout << "Base:~Base()" << endl; }
};

class A : public Base {
public:
  ~A() { cout << "A:~A()" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  {
    A a;
    static_cast<Base>(a);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

In this code
I call the `static_cast` to covert the A to Base,
the output tells me that it calls the `~Base()` twice?
why the `static_cast` make the destructor be called?

Comment: You may want `static_cast<Base&>(a);` instead.

Comment: You can't change the type of a thing. Conversion, whether explicit or not, doesn't really *convert* an object to a different type; it creates something new that has the target type, based on the thing you convert from.

Answer (score 4):

`static_cast<Base>(a);` constructs a temporary `Base`, which is copied from `a`. After the full expression the temporary gets destroyed, the destructor of `Base` is called.

After that, when get out of the scope `a` gets destroyed, the destructor of `A` and `Base` are called in order. Note that this has nothing to do with the `static_cast`.